# The Center in a MapContainer in React-Leaflet-js Won't Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've started to use React.js lately and was working on a project using React-Leaflet-js. My problem is that my `MapContainer` doesn't change the `center` of the page whenever the `position` variable in the following code is updated:

```
...
  render() {
    const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng];
    return (
      <MapContainer
      className="map"
      center={position}
      zoom={this.state.zoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}>
...
```

For reference, the `state` variable that is being updated looks like this:

```
    state = {
    location: {
      lat: 40.7128,
      lng: -74.0060,
    },
    haveUsersLocation: false,
    zoom: 13,
  }
```

What's weird is that a `marker` with a `position` set to `{position}` will automatically update when the `position` variable changes but not the `center` of the `MapContainer`. I'm not sure why the `map` doesn't respond and adjust its `center`.

Note: I tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265840/want-to-update-the-center-of-mapcontainer-of-react-leaflet-js)  but it didn't answer my question. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `center` property just initializes the map, if you want to update the center of the map actually shown you have to use either [`setView`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview) or [`flyTo`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview) if you want a smooth animation. In order to get a Leaflet Map reference you need to use the hook [`useMap`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap).

```js
function FlyMapTo() {

    const map = useMap()

    useEffect(() => {
        map.flyTo(position)
    }, [position])

    return null
}

return (
<MapContainer
      className="map"
      center={position}
      zoom={this.state.zoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}>
    <FlyMapTo />
</MapContainer>
)
```